# Cannot get RowExpander to work in Ext JS

Tags: extjs, grid, panel

I've been scouring the Internet for a week now trying to figure out why I can't get a simple rowexpander to work. I believe I've tried just about everything.

Here's my code:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.metadata.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.metadatalist',
    title: '<center>Results</center>',
    store: 'Metadata', 
    requires: ['Ext.*'],
    collapsible: true,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: [
            { xtype: 'tbtext',  text: 'Loading...', itemId: 'recordNumberItem'  },
            '->',
            { text: 'Print', itemId: 'print' },
            '-',
            { text: 'Export', itemId: 'export' }
        ]
    }],
    initComponent: function() {
        this.columns = [
            {header: 'Technical Name',  dataIndex: 'TECH_NAME', flex: 4, tdCls: 'grid_cell'},
            {header: 'Privacy', dataIndex: 'PRIVACY_INDICATOR', flex: 3, tdCls: 'grid_cell'}
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments); //Calls the parent method of the current method in order to override 

        var store = this.getStore(); //Retrieving number of records returned
            textItem = this.down('#recordNumberItem');
            textItem.setText('Number of records: ' + store.getCount());

            var val = Ext.getCmp('criteria_1_input').getValue();
            store.filter('KBE_ID', val); 

    },

    plugins: [{
        ptype: 'rowexpander',
        id: 'rowexpangder',
            rowBodyTpl : [
                '<p>Name <b>{KBE_ID}</b></p>'
            ]
       }]
});
```

In Firefox (using Firebug) my entire app breaks when I attempt to put the plugin onto the grid. In IE9, it's telling me:

```
`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'substring': object is null or undefined`
```

A couple things to note: 
-I don't have a web server (i.e. Tomcat) set up
-I'm using version 4.1.1
-I'm creating this view using ' xtype: 'metadalist' ' in my app.js

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpanderView` class loaded?

Not sure how the wildcards work, but you should try to require the exact class:

```
//...    
requires: ['Ext.*', 'Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpanderView'],
//...
```

Edit: Also, you should use `pluginId` instead of `id` for the plugin.

Comment: I suggest you use Chrome or FF debugger (press F12 > script/sources panel). Make sure script execution pauzes on errors. You can then lookup the missing class in the callstack. You can find more on ExtJs debugging here: http://www.sencha.com/learn/debugging-ext-js-applications